# Proving that a function is a contraction

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

The question is:

Find values of $a$ such that the function $f(x)=ax^2 -1$ is a contraction on the interval $[1,2]$.

I looked up the definition of a function being a contraction on the interval and found that $f: [1,2]\rightarrow [1,2]$ is a contraction if there exists $k$, $0<k<1$ such that
$d(f(x),f(y)) \le k \;d(x,y)$.

I don't know whether I should specify a value of $k$ or express $a$ in terms of $k$ and also which metric to use.

Comment: Well, if there is no metric mentioned explicitly always use Euclidean one. I think you should use latter approach. That is, given $k$ you have to find values for $a$.

Answer (score 2):

The metric is just the Euclidean metric, $d(x,y) = |x-y|$. A standard technique is to use the derivative to give bounds on the contraction constant. Since the derivative here is $2ax$, $k=|4a|$ will give a bound on $d(f(x), f(y))$ by $k d(x, y)$. You want $0<k<1$.

Note that after doing this, you still need to check the conditions on $a$ under which $f$ maps $[1,2]$ into $[1,2]$.

Comment: Could you explain more specificly how you got k=|4a| from derivative?

Comment: $d(f(x),f(y))/d(x,y)$ is precisely the (absolute value of the) difference quotient which defines the derivative. By the mean value theorem, the difference quotient of any pair of numbers in $[1,2]$ is bounded by the derivative on $(1,2)$. This shows $d(f(x), f(y)) < |4a| d(x,y)$, because $|2ax| < |4a|$ on $x \in (1,2)$.